# VSCode loads the wrong python version in the interactive window

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the Interactive window of VSCode, but it loads the wrong version of Python. I want it to load the version of the virtual environment (shown bottom left), but it defaults to something else.

I have tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503907/vscode-jupyter-loads-incorrect-version-of-python), but I can't simply click the version and change it because it isn't included in the drop down list. I have tried adjusting the settings.json file `python.defaultInterpreterPath` but that didn't work (perhaps my syntax is wrong). I have also made sure that `jupyter` is installed in the virtual environment.

I always run VSCode in the project folder from the command line using `code .` but strangely, something that has worked is running it using `code` (without the period). This is not a solution however, because the workspace folder is not updated, meaning that when I change the project I'm working on, VSCode opens in previous workspace.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete all the files and folders under this location:

```
C:\Users\${UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
```

**Others:**

The python interpreter of the `.ipynb` file was stored in the database located at:

```
C:\Users\${UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
```

Such as:

[image]

If you open a new `.ipynb` file in the VSCode which name has not storaged in the database, you will need to select the interpreter.

It's different from the interactive. You can find, any time you reopen the VSCode, the last time you created interactive will be disappear.

Comment: @Lawrence Please let me know the result.